# Angular17 & Primeng17 - onSelectAllChange Primeng with filterCallback

Tags: angular, primeng

This is an Angular Component which is designed to set filter on a table from a dropdown menu (p-multiselect) will be called back to the table component via filtercallback.

```html
<p-columnFilter [field]="getField(column)" [showMenu]="false" [showClearButton]="false">
  <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-value let-filter="filterCallback">
  <p-multiSelect
        (onChange)="onChangeFilterCallback(filter, $event)"
        (onSelectAllChange)="onSelectAllFilterCallback(filter, $event, value)"
        [selectAll]="selectAll"
        [appendTo]="'body'"
        [emptyFilterMessage]="'dataTable.multiSelEmptyFilter' | translate"
        [filterPlaceHolder]="'dataTable.multiSelFilterPlaceholder' | translate"
        [ngModel]="value"
        [options]="column.enumConfig.options"
        [resetFilterOnHide]="true"
        [style]="{ width: '100%' }"
        [placeholder]="'dataTable.multiSelPlaceholder' | translate"
        [selectedItemsLabel]="'{0} ' + ('dataTable.columns_selected' | translate)"
        [maxSelectedLabels]="2"
      >
 </p-multiSelect>
```

typescript looks like this:

```
 selectAll = false;

 onChangeFilterCallback(filter: (a) => void, event) {
    filter(event?.value);
  }

  onSelectAllFilterCallback(filter: (a) => void, event, value) {
    value = event?.checked ? [...this.column.enumConfig.options] : [];
    this.selectAll = event?.checked;
    event.updateModel(value, event?.originalEvent);
    filter(this.selectedColumns);
  }
```

At latest versions of primeng `p-multiselect`, the `(onChange)` event will not be triggered when select all options in the menu. As far as I understand, this was implemented to gain access to the selectAll Logic when having massive amounts of options. Now the problem in the code is, that it define the model via `p-template` and `let-value`. As far as I understand, this is a one way binding to prevent loops because the model will be defined and updated via filtercallback and sent back from the parent. The code runs into an error when I set the `[(model)]` to two way binding. How can I manually update the model when defined from `p-template`?